# How to prevent error with two combining attributes in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to MVC4.  I have an application that exchanges quite a lot of data from the server to the client.  All methods are executed via jQuery AJAX calls. To keep time / bandwidth down I have implemented a custom attribute to handle the compression on my controller methods:

```
public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Fairly standard and works OK.  However, I'm now trying to also add a custom attribute to check that the session still exists, and if not redirect to the login page (via a logout function).  The second attribute is as follows:

```
public class SessionExpireFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {

    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if ( ctx.Session != null ) {

            // check if a new session id was generated
            if ( ctx.Session.IsNewSession ) {

                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers[ "Cookie" ];
                if ( ( null != sessionCookie ) && ( sessionCookie.IndexOf ( "ASP.NET_SessionId" ) >= 0 ) ) {

                    ctx.Response.Redirect ( "~/Home/Logout" );
                    //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Logout");
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting ( filterContext );
    }
}
```

The problem is that this generates the following error:

"Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."

I've tried replacing `ctx.Response.Redirect......` with `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Logout")`, this removes the error but doesn't tell the client to actually redirect.

I've tried searching online with no luck, and I'm at the end of my ability to solve.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, or advise on a better way to handle one or the other above please?

Comment: I am doing some guessing, thus a *comment*, and not an answer: have you tried `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("~/Home/Logout");` or returning the actual targeted ViewResult?

Comment: Hi G. Stoynev,  Thanks for responding.  I have now tried it, albeit with `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("~/Home/Index", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary());` (a second parameter is required) however I now get a Server Error (500) when examining the xhr in Chromes Developer Tools.